# Show users that voted_for a post with thumbs_up gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rubygems, undefined

I am using the thumbsup gem to allow users to vote on microposts and now I am trying to render all of the users that have voted for a select micropost. All of the voting functionality and routes work fine, however I am now getting the error from my Micropost controller:

```
undefined method `voted_for?'
```

micropost controller:

```
def into_it  #for the view; displays who likes the post
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @users = User.voted_for?(@micropost)
  render 'show_users_into_it'
end
```

micropost model:

```
acts_as_voteable
```

User model:

```
acts_as_voter
```

Schema info:

```
# Table name: users
#  id                       
#  name            
#  email    

# Table name: microposts
#  id         :integer       
#  comment    :text
#  user_id    :integer    

# Table name: votes
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  vote          :boolean          default(FALSE), not null
#  voteable_id   :integer          not null
#  voteable_type :string(255)      not null
#  voter_id      :integer
#  voter_type    :string(255)
```

Do I have to do some sort of SQL query instead is there no simple way? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an undefined method `voted_for?` because you are calling it on the User class instead of an instance of the user.

I think the method you're looking for is [voters_who_voted](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/blob/master/lib/acts_as_voteable.rb#L105-L107) which would be used like:

```
def into_it  #for the view; displays who likes the post
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @users = @micropost.voters_who_voted
  render 'show_users_into_it'
end
```

Comment: thanks im pretty new to programming concepts, makes sense. cheers.

Answer (score -1):

this is because  @users = User.voted_for?(@micropost) will return true or false ,but not the instance object.  try looking at this link http://openrails.blogspot.com/2012/01/thumbs-up-in-rails.html